# Angular js not getting textbox value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angularJs code is not getting the value of the textbox, I have done this before and cant see what I am doing wrong!

In the html page I have a textbox and a button :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Date</label> 
    <input type="text" ng-modal="items.appdate" placeholder="Appointment Date" class="form-control">
</div>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs" ng-click="saveAppointment()"><strong>Create</strong></button>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.items = {
    appdate: ''
}

$scope.saveAppointment=function(){
    console.log($scope.items);
}
```

but the log is just

> Object {appdate: ""}

Why isnt it picking up the textbox?

Comment: even if i try to pass items.appdate in the function its undefined

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo.

Is `ng-model` and not ng-modal

Check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for documentation.

Your code has to be like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="items.appdate" placeholder="Appointment Date" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ng-modal with ng-model.